# 10 title at Montecarlo for Nadal is a record?

Tags: trivia, tennis, records, atp, wta

Nadal has won his 10th title on clay of Montecarlo, is this a record for winning of a single tennis tournament?

I would like to consider only ATP/WTA tournaments from the Open Era that begins in 1968, and only about singles tournaments, both

For example those are the record for Gran Slam category:

- men: [Nadal won 9 times the French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Grand_Slam_men%27s_singles_champions)
- women: [Martina Navatrilova won 9 times Wimbledon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Grand_Slam_women%27s_singles_champions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the ATP World Tour website (emphasis mine):

> Rafael Nadal captured an incredible 10th Monte-Carlo Rolex Masters crown on Sunday in beating fellow Spaniard Albert Ramos-Vinolas 6-1, 6-3 in the 76-minute final. Nadal’s 29th ATP World Tour Masters 1000 title, one shy of record-holder Novak Djokovic (30), marks **the first time in the Open Era (since April 1968) that any man has won a singles tournament on 10 occasions.**

From: [Nadal Wins Historic 10th Monte-Carlo Title](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/nadal-ramos-vinolas-monte-carlo-2017-final) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170425182049/http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/news/nadal-ramos-vinolas-monte-carlo-2017-final))

---

For WTA, there is a section Most titles / finals at a single tournament in the Wikipedia article [WTA Tour records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WTA_Tour_records#Most_titles_.2F_finals_at_a_single_tournament) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=WTA_Tour_records&oldid=776941849#Most_titles_.2F_finals_at_a_single_tournament)), which lists 12 titles of [Martina Navratilova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martina_Navratilova) at [Ameritech Cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ameritech_Cup) (Chicago) as the record.

---

Information about most titles (and most consecutive titles) at a particular tournament is also given in the Wikipedia article [Tennis tournament records and statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennis_tournament_records_and_statistics) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tennis_tournament_records_and_statistics&oldid=776825260)). However, this article is not restricted to the [Open Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Era).

---

**EDIT:** It is probably worth adding that no too long after this question Nadal won his 10th title in [Barcelona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcelona_Open_(tennis)#Winner_of_most_singles_titles). And in the same calendar year Nadal won his 10th singles title at [French Open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_French_Open_%E2%80%93_Men%27s_Singles), becoming the first player to achieve this at a Grand Slam tournament.

Answer (score 0):

Nadal holds multiple records that involve the Monte-Carlo Masters :

1. **11** titles, most titles at any tournament
2. **8** consecutive titles at any single tournament, 2005 - 2012
3. **46** match win streak at any single tournament, 2005 to 2013 final
4. **12** finals, most finals at any tournament
5. Won a Masters at both singles and doubles, 2008 (record shared with Jim Courier)